# Android: click within WebView causes callback to Android application

Tags: android, callback

I'm thinking of implementing a HTML welcome panel to our Android app, which presents news and offers on the start-up screen. My question is now, if I present an offer to a specific place (with an `id string`) can I trigger a callback from the WebView (maybe via Java Script) to the Android app and passing that `id string` to make it start a new `Activity` which loads and shows data from a server (JSON) depending on that `id string`?

The second part is already implemented and working. My main concern is how to get the `id string` from the HTML WebView back to the Android app when the user clicks on it.

We prefer to use a WebView for that specific welcome panel, because it gives us more flexibility to customize by using HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes indeed you can good sir! If you show the data in a javascript Alert, then you can capture it like this. It might not be the most neat way, but it works =)

```
private void loadWebViewStuff() {
        myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
        myWebView.loadUrl(URL);
}


final class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    @Override
    public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
        //"message" is what is shown in the alert, here we can do whatever with it
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's probably better to use [WebView.addJavascriptInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29), rather than overload onJsAlert.