# How to get the callback of input area click of a WebView in Android

Tags: android, webview

I am developing a keyboard in Android. The keyboard contains a WebView. When the user clicks on an input area of a web page in the WebView, a keyboard panel should be shown. After I checked all the callbacks of WebView, I cannot find any callbacks were invoked. How could I know the user clicking on an input area and do something?

Comment: use javascript and a javascript interface binding on your webview

Comment: @njzk2 The web page is not under control just like google.com. We cannot add javascript in the page.

Comment: of course you can. You can just execute js on the page after it is loaded.

Answer (score -1):

Try to check it:

```
public class WebViewClicker extends Activity implements OnTouchListener, Handler.Callback {

    private static final int CLICK_ON_WEBVIEW = 1;
    private static final int CLICK_ON_URL = 2;

    private final Handler handler = new Handler(this);

    private WebView webView;
    private WebViewClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.web_view_clicker);

        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);
        webView.setOnTouchListener(this);

        client = new WebViewClient(){ 
            @Override public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) { 
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(CLICK_ON_URL);
                return false;
            } 
        }; 

        webView.setWebViewClient(client);
        webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.web && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(CLICK_ON_WEBVIEW, 500);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (msg.what == CLICK_ON_URL){
            handler.removeMessages(CLICK_ON_WEBVIEW);
            return true;
        }
        if (msg.what == CLICK_ON_WEBVIEW){
            Toast.makeText(this, "WebView clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    }
```

What I did find is that a WebView will send touch events to an OnTouchListener. It does have its own onTouchEvent method but I only ever seemed to get MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE using that method.

So given that we can get events on a registered touch event listener, the only problem that remains is how to circumvent whatever action you want to perform for a touch when the user clicks a URL.

This can be achieved with some fancy Handler footwork by sending a delayed message for the touch and then removing those touch messages if the touch was caused by the user clicking a URL.

Comment: This is only for the user clicking a URL. What I need is a callback invoked when user  click input area.

Comment: check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236362/android-click-within-webview-causes-callback-to-android-application