# Get the webview html string with the changed controls status

Tags: android, android-webview

Am working in an android application and I want to load a set of radio buttons in the webview where I get the Html string. I have loaded the html string successfully into the webview by [loadData()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadData(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method . I also triggered the click event of the radio buttons by adding [addJavascriptInterface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/JavascriptInterface.html).

After all these When I click a button I want to get the full html string loaded in the webview and I want the radio button current status(Check or unchecked) in the html string which **currently am not getting**.

How to get the html string with the changed status of the radio buttons.

Html string :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;"/>
</head>
<body>
<form>
What color do you prefer?<br />
<input type="radio" name="colors" id="red" />Red<br />
<input type="radio" name="colors" id="blue" />Blue<br />
<input type="radio" name="colors" id="green" />Green
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does anyone have a solution to this question..

Comment: Please see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236362/android-click-within-webview-causes-callback-to-android-application)