# How to get callback onclick from third party library payment getway view on webview in Android?

Tags: android

I have web view and loading URL on it and there is a third party Submit button on the web view screen. After tap on Submit button i want to call back inside the app of the third party payment gateway.Please help me

Comment: check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236362/android-click-within-webview-causes-callback-to-android-application

Comment: i have used this@papan